# Align SVG and Text in a column CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, mobile, navbar

I am currently creating a website and i am having problems with the mobile layout. My mobile navbar is at the bottom of the screen and the text should be directly under the displayed SVG. [image: Picture of navbar]

This is how it currently looks. I tried using both flexbox and grid but could get it to work. margin-left was also an option but then the left button is too farther away from the border then most right button.

Currently my Code looks like this:

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 981px){
    .navbar{
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 5.5rem;
        padding-top: -0.1rem;
    }

    .logo{
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar-nav{
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .nav-link {
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        color: var(--accent-color);
    }

    main{
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
    }

    .nav-link svg {
        width: 2.3rem;
        min-width: 2rem;
        margin: 0 1.5rem;
        margin-top: -1rem;
    }
    .nav-item .link-text {
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav-item {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
}
```

HTML/JS:

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <header>
        <nav className="navbar">
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
        <li className="logo">
          <a href="/" className="nav-link">
            <svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0, 0, 400,368.05555555555554">
             
            </svg>
            <span className="link-text">CCR</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a href="/" className="nav-link">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"></svg>
            <span className="link-text home">Start</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a href="/training" className="nav-link">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"></svg>
            <span className="link-text training">Training</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a href="/about" className="nav-link">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"></svg>
            <span className="link-text about">Über uns</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a href="/gallary" className="nav-link">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"></svg>
            <span className="link-text gallary">Bildgalerie</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a href="/contact" className="nav-link">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512</svg>
            <span className="link-text contact">Kontakt</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Note: I edited out all SVG Files to shorten the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your use of **flex-box**. When you go to use `display: flex;` the affected elements are only the direct children, not the children's children. In this case you put `flex-direction: columns;` a `nav-item`, but the only thing that will go to column is the element `a(nav-link)`, and since it is the only child the difference will be zero.

So, intead of

```css
.nav-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

try this

```css
.nav-link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Almost worked but its still not centered under the svg

Comment: I don't know exactly how it is now... But to center it add `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`

Comment: I made it work. I forgot to remove padding and margin from the desktop version